# How long does the present last in the present tense?

Tags: present-tense

It can be further discussed philosophically or physically, but I want to know linguistically.

Does it depend on the speaker? I mean, depending on each speaker, it can mean a present second, a present minute, or even a present year?

Technically, if I say I’m playing soccer, can it mean I’m playing soccer in January, that is, in the present year?

Comment: It depends on the _context_. You might tell an old friend you haven't been in touch with for years "I'm living in London now", or someone giving instructions over the phone "OK, I'm turning the knob now, nothing's happening yet."

Answer (score 1):

The "present" is now, at this instant of time. It doesn't last for more than a moment.

So "I'm playing soccer" means that I'm playing at the instant that I make that utterance.  As it is a continuous tense, we understand that the action is ongoing, so in order for you to "be playing soccer" now, you must have started a little in the past, and you must be expecting to continue a little into the future.

Simple present can also mean "at this instant of time".  A football commentator might say "Harry passes the ball".  The meaning is that the action started and finished at the same moment of time as the commentator spoke the words.

There is no limit on how long a continuous tense might extend into the past and future, it only means that something is temporary:  "I'm working as a taxi driver, but I'm a qualified brain surgeon"  The speaker might have been working as a taxi driver for several years, but he still considers it to be temporary.

And there are all sorts of non-present senses of the "present" tense.  Simple present can be used for generally true facts  "I like dogs"  (right now, and at all times). And present continuous can be used for future events that proceed from the present.  "I'm visiting my aunt next week"  (I know because right now there is definite plan).

However if it is December, then to talk about the past (11 months ago in January) you would use a past tense, not a present tense.